# Populate SourceList in Xamarin.Mac app

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, mono, xamarin

I am creating my first Mac application using Mono and Xamarin Studio since I plan on reusing some C# code I have from a Windows version. So I am completely new to both XCode and Mono. I have just started to learn all the Cocoa stuff.

I am trying to create a sidebar similar to the one in Finder which I want to use for navigation. I have so far figured out I should use the SourceList object and have added it to my interface using the Interface Builder in XCode. But how do I populate it with headers and items (with icons)?

By default I see a sample header and a sample item in the IB but they don't show up when I run my app from Xamarin Studio. The SourceList is just empty.

Has anyone else done something similar to this? I can't find any good examples or tutorials on how to properly populate the SourceList.

EDIT:

I have now finally found the answer. It is a combination of the answer here by TheNextman and also his answer to a follow-up question here: [Create NSView programatically in Xamarin Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544025/create-nsview-programatically-in-xamarin-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465528/creating-a-simple-nsoutlineview-datasource-with-monomac) will help you populate the source list (which is just a styled NSOutlineView) with data.

Since the source list is 'view based', you will need to implement a couple of extra methods from the [NSOutlineViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. Off the top of my head:

`outlineView:isGroupItem:` - specify whether the item is a 'header' or not
`outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:item:` - return the cell for the given column/item

Comment: I have seen that answer before but it only gave me badly aligned text. No headers or icons. I am unfamiliar with objective-c, doing this in C#. So can you explain "outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:item:"? Is that a method name?

Comment: I suggest you familiarise yourself with the delegate pattern as used in Cocoa, or this will all be quite confusing: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11. Next you can learn how to apply this to C# - I can't find any specific documentation for Mac, but there are samples and the iOS documentation also covers it: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events (it is similar enough on Mac)

Comment: I still don't think I fully understand. I have created a new class which inherits from NSOutlineViewDelegate and implements the methods IsGroupItem and GetCell (which just returns `new NSCell("Foo")`). I then set `MyOutlineView.Delegate = new MyDelegate()`. But still nothing shows up.

Comment: I do get the items, but there's no text or anything. They are selectable and there appears to be both headers and regular items. I have tried to override both the GetCell and GetSelectString methods but no success. There's also a GetView method which I can override but I don't know how to return a view with a text in it.

Comment: @ChristofferBrodd-Reijer I have posted an answer to your other question, since I think that this answers your original question here

Comment: Thanks for the awesomeness! Now all I need is to fix the Hide/Show but I'll try to figure that out myself. Thanks again!